# Plotting a Datetime Bar Graph with Pandas with different xlabels

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot a bar graph that has only a few entries of data in each column of a pandas DataFrame with a bar graph. This is successful, but not only does it have the wrong y-axis limits, it also makes the x ticks very closely spaced so that the graph is useless. I would like to change the step rate to be about every week or so and only display day, month and year. I have the following DataFrame:

```
       Observed  WRF
2014-06-28 12:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 13:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 14:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 15:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 16:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 17:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 18:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 19:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 20:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 21:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 22:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-28 23:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 00:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 01:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 02:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 03:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 04:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 05:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 06:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 07:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 08:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 09:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 10:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 11:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 12:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 13:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 14:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 15:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 16:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-06-29 17:00:00       0.0  0.0
                      ...  ...
2014-07-04 02:00:00       0.0002    0.0
2014-07-04 03:00:00       0.2466    0.0
2014-07-04 04:00:00       0.7103    0.0
2014-07-04 05:00:00       0.9158    1.93521e-13
2014-07-04 06:00:00       0.6583    0.0
2014-07-04 07:00:00       0.3915    0.0
2014-07-04 08:00:00       0.1249    0.0
2014-07-04 09:00:00       0.0       0.0
                      ...  ...
2014-08-30 07:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 08:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 09:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 10:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 11:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 12:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 13:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 14:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 15:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 16:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 17:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 18:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 19:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 20:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 21:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 22:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-30 23:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 00:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 01:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 02:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 03:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 04:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 05:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 06:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 07:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 08:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 09:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 10:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 11:00:00       0.0  0.0
2014-08-31 12:00:00       0.0  0.0
```

And the following code to plot it:

```
df4.plot(kind='bar',edgecolor='none',figsize=(16,8),linewidth=2, color=((1,0.502,0),'black'))
plt.legend(prop={'size':16})
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=.1)
plt.title('Five Day WRF Model Comparison Near %.2f,%.2f' %(lat,lon),fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel('Hourly Accumulated Precipitation [mm]',fontsize=18,color='black')
ax4=plt.gca()
maxs4=df4.max()
ax4.set_ylim([0, maxs4.max()])
ax4.xaxis_date()
ax4.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5, -0.05) 
plt.xlabel('Time',fontsize=18,color='black')
plt.show()
```

The y-axis starts at 0, but continues to about double the maximum value of the y-limit. The x-axis counts by hours, which is what I separated the data by, so that makes sense. However, it is not a helpful display.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime 
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter

# Sample data
df_origin = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(datetime(2014,6,28,12,0,0), 
 datetime(2014,8,30,12,0,0), freq='1H'), columns=['Valid Time'])
df_origin = df_origin .set_index('Valid Time')
df_origin ['Precipitation'] = np.random.uniform(low=0., high=10., size=(len(df_origin.index)))
df_origin .loc[20:100, 'Precipitation'] = 0.
df_origin .loc[168:168*2, 'Precipitation'] = 0. # second week has to be dry

# Plotting
df_origin.plot(y='Precipitation',kind='bar',edgecolor='none',figsize=(16,8),linewidth=2, color=((1,0.502,0)))
plt.legend(prop={'size':16})
plt.subplots_adjust(left=.1, right=0.9, top=0.9, bottom=.1)
plt.title('Precipitation (WRF Model)',fontsize=24)
plt.ylabel('Hourly Accumulated Precipitation [mm]',fontsize=18,color='black')
ax = plt.gca()
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

# skip ticks for X axis
ax.set_xticklabels([dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for dt in df_origin.index])
for i, tick in enumerate(ax.xaxis.get_major_ticks()):
    if (i % (24*7) != 0): # 24 hours * 7 days = 1 week
        tick.set_visible(False)

plt.xlabel('Time',fontsize=18,color='black')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So, I guess it's more of a labeling sort of question. I apologize for not having as much clarity. I am looking to simply change the xlabels to be weekly rather than hourly while still maintaining the same bins. So, data would be grouped by hours, but the xlabel would not be.

Comment: Yes, you question is not quite clear. What you want is more easy I made a change to above code.

Comment: Thank you. That looks very nice.