# Panda DataFrame Plot xaxis.set_major_locator leaves ticks blank on bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I currently have a pandas dataframe that looks like this

```
                     items_out       items_in
day
2018-04-10              -5               0
2018-04-11               0               2
2018-04-12              -2               3
2018-04-13               0               0
2018-04-14               0               0
2018-04-15               0               0
2018-04-16               0               4
2018-04-17               0               0
2018-04-18              -3               5
2018-04-19               0               0
2018-04-20               0               0
2018-04-21               0               7
2018-04-22               0               0
2018-04-23               0               0
2018-04-24               0               0
```

I am trying to create a bar chart that looks like this

[image]

The problem is the date does not show up at all. Here is my current code of what I am currently trying as well as some commented stuff I tried (I have been palying around with various things)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=inventory_movement)
df.set_index('day',inplace=True)
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [18, 10]
plt.rcParams["axes.grid.axis"] = "y"
#plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = True

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax1 = df.plot(kind='bar',y='items_out',ax=ax,color='r',width=.7)
ax2 = df.plot(kind='bar',y='items_in',ax=ax,color='g',width=.7)\

ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax2.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m-%Y'))


plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

#ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator())
#ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(IndexFormatter(df.index))


plt.savefig('/tmp/inventory_change_rate.png',bbox_inches='tight')
```

I tried this method here, but it gave me a single date on the left and thats it. So I think I am forming my dataframe wrong some how?

[Plotting a Datetime Bar Graph with Pandas with different xlabels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38294137/plotting-a-datetime-bar-graph-with-pandas-with-different-xlabels)

Comment: You can in general not use matplotlib dates locators and formatters for pandas plots. Instead you will need to plot with matplotlib in order to be able to use them.

Comment: Hmm, ok thanks. Seems to be a bit more difficult than I expected. Thanks for the help.